# hive: Using collect_set with a delimiter

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to use collect_set in a hive query to group the columns on a group by condition. Each row is having spaces as delimiters instead of ',' or something. How to change the delimiter to ',' or any other delimiter in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Naga Vemprala

Comment: Can you please show your query, table definition, and some sample data?

Comment: @JeremyBeard Thank you for your time. As I am working on a confidential data, I am giving here a sample query. My query was very simple: select serial_num, collect_set(customer_lastName) as concatenate_lastNames from External_Table group by serial_num; After the query is executed, I am getting last names as "lastname1 lastname2 lastname3" etc just with a space separated. But I want a comma separated field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`COLLECT_SET` returns an array, with which you can then concatenate the entries into a single comma-separated value using `CONCAT_WS`:

```
select serial_num, concat_ws(",", collect_set(customer_lastName)) as concatenate_lastNames from External_Table group by serial_num
```